# How to trace a program

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, gdb

I am working on a gui program in Linux. i have no idea about how the code implements.
You can imagine the gui has some input and output fields, a click button. After you input some numbers in the input fields and click the button, some numbers will show in the output fields.
Now I want to know what functions will be invoked when I click the button, and which variable in the source code that is shown in a text field (calculation result）in the GUI.
What tool should I use?

Comment: Do you have the source or not? If not, do you have a debug build or only the "normal" program?

Comment: i　ｈａｖｅ　ｔｈｅ　ｓｏｕｒｃｅ　ｃｏｄｅ．　Ｔｈｅ　ｏｎｌｙ　ｐｒｏｂｌｅｍ　ｉｓ　ｔｈｅ　ｃｏｄｅ　ｉｓ　ｓｏ　ｃｏｍｐｌｅｘ　ｔｈａｔ　ｉ　ｃａｎｎｏｔ　ｕｎｄｅｒｓｔａｎｄ　ｔｏｔａｌｌｙ．

Comment: Well, I fear you're on your own. We don't know the source, and pasting it completely will get your question closed. (Btw., why don't you use the normal character symbols?)